# Dataframe subsets retain information from parent dataframe

Tags: r

I assume this is used as a feature in data.frame() but it has presented a lot of problems for evaluating training and test sets for some packages. For example if you utilize h2o for machine learning, import a dataset, and subset the dataframe based on some random sample of the data, the h2o model builder will have access to the FULL original dataframe with all factor levels and all data. As such, if you try something like h2o.predict(model,newdata=dataset[test,]) your prediction will simply copy the response in the dataset over (tested for a deep learning model). You can see the factor retention below:

```
y = as.factor(c("1","0","0","1"))
X = c(5,4,3,4)
data = data.frame(y,X)

train = data[c(1,4),]
test = data[c(2,3),]

trainingData = data[train,]
trainingData
levels(trainingData[,1])
[1] "0" "1"
```

Now, I've been able to solve the factor information retention, but I'm not sure how to remove information from the parent dataframe in the new subset. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: For anyone who has had the factor problem, it's as simple as applying function droplevels().

Comment: Standby but I may have come up with a solution. It appears to be an issue arising from coercing an object of type h2o to an object of type vector. However, if you coerce the h2o object back to a dataframe you'll get a dataframe with all information and the predictions which you can extract as always via data[,1]

Comment: The retention of factor levels is normal, not sure about the h2o specifics.

Comment: Yes I know that. I had some trouble some time ago with this but I had solved it then. I mainly used that as an example. Maybe I should've shown the full h2o process to show how h2o will predict for all observations in the original dataframe.

Comment: OK, I'm voting to close as "no longer reproducible", hope that's ok!